# Change number of request in executing

Tags: request, jmeter

I am working on Apache Jmeter. I simulated a DOS attack so I have Http Request that send 20 request per second. I want to decrease request when it is running and attacking, Can I change a number of Threads(users) in executing? or use something instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Constant Throughput Timer](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-throughput-constant-timer) to change "requests per second" on the fly. Despite "Constant" word in its name "Target Throughput" can be a JMeter Property which can be changed while test is being executed via i.e. [Beanshell Server](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#beanshell_server)

Other option is using [Throughput Shaping Timer](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/) which has more features and flexibility w.r.t. load profile definition, it is easier to use.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, what should I do with number of user in thread?

Comment: Provide enough threads as timers can only "pause" threads to limit throughput to defined rate, for instance create twice as many as your desired throughput is

Comment: I want to simulate rate limiting. So first i need 100 request after a while I should limit the request, for example request should decrease 80.